# How to stop kable from repeating one row to the end of the page

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

As the title suggests, I wrote an Rmarkdown file to print a table, and for a reason I cannot understand, it's taking the first row of the table and repeating it until the end of the page is reached:

[image: messed up table]

It seems like the table is somehow being set to a fixed width, but I'm not sure why that is and I'm also not sure why only the one row is repeating. I would like it to look normal. The rest of the page not covered by the table can just be blank. Thanks for your help.

I have tried messing around with the `full_width` parameter in `kable_styling`, this didn't make a difference.

Here's a reproducible example. This is the header:

```
---
title: ""
always_allow_html: yes
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
geometry: margin=0.3in
header-includes:
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \setmainfont{Helvetica}
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
- \DeclareTextCommand{\nobreakspace}{TU}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }
documentclass: article
classoption: a4paper
---
```

And here's an R chunk that reproduces the issue, note I used setting `{r, echo=FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}`.

```
# Packages
suppressMessages(library(extrafont))
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressMessages(library(pander))
suppressMessages(library(kableExtra))

# Data
table_info <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=1:4, c=1:4, d=1:4, e=1:4, f=1:4, g=1:4, h=1:4, i=1:4)

nrow_table <- nrow(table_info)
ncol_table <- ncol(table_info)

column_ems <- c("2em", rep("1.125em", ncol_table - 1))

fsize <- 10

  ktable <- table_info %>%
    mutate_all(linebreak) %>%
    kable(escape = FALSE, align = paste0(rep('l', ncol_table), collapse=""),
          col.names = NULL,
          booktabs = TRUE, format = "latex" , linesep = "") %>%
    row_spec(1:nrow_table, color = "darkgray") %>%
    column_spec(1, column_ems[1]) %>%
    column_spec(2, column_ems[2]) %>%
    column_spec(3, column_ems[3]) %>%
    column_spec(4, column_ems[4]) %>%
    column_spec(5, column_ems[5]) %>%
    column_spec(6, column_ems[6]) %>%
    column_spec(7, column_ems[7]) %>%
    column_spec(8, column_ems[8]) %>%
    column_spec(9, column_ems[9]) %>%
    kable_styling(font_size = fsize) %>%
    row_spec(1, align = 'c') %>%
    row_spec(2, font_size = fsize - 2)


ktable <- ktable %>% row_spec(1:(nrow_table-1), hline_after = TRUE)


ktable <- ktable %>% add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Manganese" = 2,
                                        "Phosphorus" = 2,
                                        "Potassium" = 2,
                                        "Zinc" = 2), bold = T)
}

ktable
```

The table output by this code looks like this:
[image: messed up table]

The expected output should be that same table but without all of the extra 1's in the first row below the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a `kableExtra` bug or if you are misusing it, but the problem is in the initial call to `kable()`.  You have

```
kable(escape = FALSE, align = paste0(rep('l', ncol_table), collapse=""),
```

and somewhere later, the alignment setting in LaTeX gets repeated many times.  If you change that line to

```
kable(escape = FALSE, align = 'l',
```

then the problem goes away:

[image]

Comment: This did solve my issue, and looks like it's a `kable` bug - if the `align` parameter is a vector with number of characters equal to the number of columns it's supposed to support being expanded to specify the alignment of each individual column. Thankfully I have no need for that in this case since the whole thing is left aligned anyway. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a bug. I think `kable()` docs ask for `c('l", "l", ...)` rather than `"ll..."`, and I get the right result if I change your original `align` spec to `align = rep('l', ncol_table)`.